# Maven: Create Clean .m2 from Dirty .m2 to Support Offline Builds

Tags: maven, dependencies, offline

I have a Maven project. One of the repositories is no longer available online.

My local environment has what it needs to build the project offline with -o.

What's a good way to capture only the files this project needs, to provide a copy of the artifacts to others to develop the project in the same offline manner?

I'd like to avoid providing my entire .m2 directory for efficiency.

It would be great if there was a way to save all of the build artifacts for a particular Maven project from a bloated working .m2 to a clean .m2, including only what's necessary to the project, to easily share with others.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you have a repository manager?

Comment: I have access to Artifactory but am not familiar with how to add or push the dependencies for this project to it and then get local builds to call dependencies from it (maybe settings.xml - I would prefer to avoid editing any pom.xml files). It's a more elegant solution but it would also be nice to have a strictly local solution as well.

Comment: So why not publishing your projects to that repository manager and everything is solved... Every build consumes from that... and you can delete your "cache" because the local repository is nothing than a cache... For consuming the `settings.xml` is the correct way...for publishing distributionManagement is the correct way...which shouldn't being from your local machine..only from a CI solution ....

Comment: I took your advice and got something working. I don't know if it's ideal, but thanks for the suggestion! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70910003/maven-artifcatory-reference-host-unavailable-dependencies